# Prove $ A^-=\dfrac{1}{4}(-A^2+4A+I)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Show that $ A^-=\dfrac{1}{4}(-A^2+4A+I)$

I have absolutely no clue how to do this. Could someone be kind enough to explain and provide and answer? I believe it has something to do with the Cayley-Hamiliton Theorem as the question is from that problem set but I don't understand how to use it to solve this problem. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: is $I$ the identity matrix?

Comment: Because Im trying this computation and I'm not getting the proper answer.

Comment: @kolonel It does not say explicitly but $I$ is used as an identity matrix in my class by convention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda-4)(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)=\lambda^3-4\lambda^2-\lambda+4$. So, by Cayley-Hamilton,
$$
A^3-4A^2-A+4I=0.
$$
Then $$I=\frac14\,(A+4A^2-A^3),$$ and since $A$ is invertible (its determinant is $4\ne0$) we have, multiplying by $A^{-1}$,
$$
A^{-1}=\frac14\,(I+4A-A^2).
$$

Comment: Very nice.When I tried to compute this by plugging $A$ into the formula given to derive the inverse, I did not get an inverse. Any ideas what I did wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What you always do is to multiply the equation given by Cayley-Hamilton by $A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

- Show that $|\lambda I_3 - A| = \lambda^3 - 4 \lambda^2 - \lambda + 4$
- Use Cayley Hamilton Theorem, to show that $A^3 - 4 A^2 - A + 4I_3 = 0$
- Show that A inverse exists (how?)
- Multiply the equation from step 2 with A inverse and rearrange